Groupings of set theoretic axioms, or even “algebras of axioms”
I want to understand how to group the axioms of a set theory to study the effect that each axiom has in relation to the others. Here’s what I mean:
First of all, assume “a set theory” is not a well-defined notion. In model theory, we can merely state there is some collection of formulas over a signature. Since set theories do tend to focus on one relation symbol (set membership), let’s restrict our attention to single-sorted, first-order theories with a single binary relation (and no function symbols, because I read every first-order theory with function symbols can be expressed without them in a logically equivalent way).
So, a “theory” Phi consists of formulas phi1, phi2, phi3, ….
The first part of the question is about different ways you can group the axioms of a set theory by some common theme or function. Here’s one example:

Now, I had previously considered some of my own ways to group the axioms of ZFC. For example, some axioms state plainly certain sets that exist (empty set, infinity). Some axioms state given a set you have, a new set can you form (pairing, powers, unions). Replacement and choice have struck me as similar, as they both appear to be ways of inferring new sets with the use of functions. And regularity and extensionality are somewhat similar, somewhat different: regularity is a restriction on what kinds of sets can exist, and extensionality sort of adds information about the equality relation. They both seem to assert logical truths about a universe of sets, without directly giving information on how to construct new sets. So I wonder if these axioms can be called restrictive as opposed to constructive.
But this is an informal way of groupings axioms. Are there other suggested ways of grouping the axioms? What about finding a fully formal way to express the “properties” of each axiom so it becomes clearer how they could be grouped in relation to one another?
Secondly, sometimes there is talk about how one axiom is actually equivalent to another, like choice and Zorn’s lemma. Then this opens the question of studying “algebras of axioms”. I mean that given the collection of all well-formed formulas over a signature, I am pretty sure we can study “equivalent sets of axioms” in a very elementary algebraic structure, possibly a commutative monoid. The law of composition is the logical connective “and”. This would be a way to discover how many syntactically distinct, logically equivalent “axiom strings” for ZFC there are, for example. Has anyone done this?

Just found this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/

This question belongs in math.stackexchange.com.

Yes, there are existential axioms: Empty set, Infinity, and conditional axioms that, provided already existent sets, assert the existence of new ones: Separation, Pair, Replacement.

And there are axioms specifying basic properties of sets: Extensionality, Regularity.

The standard axiomatic framework is simply too pliable to support semantic classifications of axioms, which is why ZFC and similar theories can be equivalently reformulated in a multitude of ways that interchange different types of axioms and do not even use the same base notions. One proposal I saw on constraining this boundless 'equivalence' was a la Euclid, construction postulates (empty, infinity, pair, union, power, specification, replacement, choice) vs common notions (extensionality, regularity), see Rodin, On Constructive Axiomatic Method.

Another classification, is that some Axioms are one formula, while other's are actually Axiom Schemes, one Axiom for every well-formed formula

There is also the Levy Herairchy Classification of Complexity, which classifies the Axioms ( as well as all well-formed formula) in terms of how we can write them in terms of quantifiers.
